# Application not using full display area running X11 without window manager

Tags: shell-script, x11, gui, display, arm

I am trying to run a piece of software on an arm SoC. I have x11 running and I launch manually with

```
xterm -geometry 800x480-0+0
```

while this opens up a xterm that uses the entire panel when I run the program, pylonviewer by basler I get a small box in the corner and a larger dialog box that shows on startup. The popup appears to be the appropriate size for the screen but the main gui is too small only showing the corner. I am not sure how I can force the program to match the dimensions of the display. I would prefer to do this without a window manager and manually resizing.

Thanks in advance,

**UPDATE**

Below is a screen capture of what I am seeing. I closed the dialog box that appears to work but is not the size of the screen anyway. MY screen is a 7" LCD touch screen panel

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I am not sure, but I think `geometry` parameters are to be passed to window manager. And xterm, I think, is different. The geometry parameter for xterm does not specify pixels, but character columns and lines. In your case I think it should be 800 columns x 480 lines of characters (not pixels). Can you provide some picture showing, what you get? `xwd --root -out screenshot.xwd` will make a screenshot of your display.

Comment: @nobody I updated my OP with the screen capture. Let me know if you need anything else. Thanks for the prompt reply.

Comment: Try using `-geometry` on the application. If it is a well-behaved X11 program it should take these hints. Alternatively, it may have an applications-default file where you can set width and height (list what files came in the same package as the application). Or try `xdotool` to search for the window by name and apply `windowsize` to it.

Comment: @meuh how would I apply the geometry on the application. When I launch so for my case ./pylonviewer -geometry .....?

Comment: Yes. Searching for info on pylonviewer doesn't say anything about its use from the command-line (cli), as it seems to have been designed for microsoft users who rarely use the cli, so there are probably no options. You can always try `--help`. Also, look for example scripts that might be provided with the package, eg for taking pictures automatically at a given time.

Comment: I do not know how to do it without window manager. With window manager, I use wmctrl (https://linux.die.net/man/1/wmctrl) to change window's size, position, and oher parameters.